# Spring equivalent of a servlet that loads master data after container startup

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a servlet in my webapp (based on MVC Model 2) which loads all the master data after the tomcat container loads the application context. I want to replace this with Spring based solution. Please note that it will require access to the datasource. How can I do this?

## web.xml

```
 <servlet>
        <description>Loads all master data for the application to reduce response time</description>
        <servlet-name>MasterDataLoader</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mywebapp.web.controllers.MasterDataLoader</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>10</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

## MasterDataLoader.java

```
public class MasterDataLoader extends HttpServlet {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MasterDataLoader.class);
    private static final String DATASOURCE = "dataSource";

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        loadAll();
    }       

    private void loadAll() {
        LOG.debug("Fetching all master data (menu categories, states, freight companies, tender types, product cross sells, best sellers etc.) for the application.........");
        ServletContext appContext = getServletContext();
        appContext.setAttribute("states", getAllStates());
   }

    private List<State> getAllStates() {
        LOG.debug("Fetching all states from db...");
        List<State> statesLst = null;
        try {
            DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) getServletContext().getAttribute(DATASOURCE);
            statesLst = new MasterDao(dataSource).getAllStates();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            LOG.error("Exception while fetching all states...");
            LOG.error(ex);
        }
        return statesLst;
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you write a servletcontextlistener for this purpose?

Comment: Why are you "fetching master data" instead of just using ordinary DAO, possibly with caching?

Comment: I have never used caching before and don't have much experience in Spring either hence I would like to load all the master data such as all US states and store it in applicationContext. I certainly could do that with the help of ServletContextListener but still not clear as how will I get the dataSource object in that listener.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate a method of one of your beans with `@PostConstruct`, and do the job in this method. The example provided in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) precisely does what you want to do.